# How to use jQuery and Ajax to refresh div content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I should refresh the content of a div element by clicking on the div.
I tried using `load()` method of jQuery, but it didn't work.
My code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $("#toRefresh").load("articoli.html");
    });
});
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<div class="col-md-8 main-div" id="toRefresh">
    <h3 class="lato-font" style="color: white;">Elenco eventi</h3>
    <div class="conf-div">
        <div class="conf-div-content lato-font text-left">  
            <div class="conference-div" id="click">
                <div class="conference-content">
                    <img class="role" src="images/roles-icons/chair-active.png">
                    <img class="role" src="images/roles-icons/author-active.png">
                    <img class="role" src="images/roles-icons/reviewer-active.png">
                    <p class="title">Conferenza 1</p>
                    <img class="arrow" src="images/arrow-right.svg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I also tried to insert the `div class="conference-div"` into an `a` element, but it didn't work.
How can i fix that?

Comment: Make sure "articoli.html" is in the place you are expecting it to be. There you assume is at the same level(folder). Then, you should use some sort of debugger like Firefox Developer tools or Chrome Dev tools, to check for Console Errors and Network statuses.

Comment: soounds like correct, check the console.

Comment: Side note:  Instead of:  `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#click").click(function(){`   you might want to look into .on() as well ...  If you have dynamic elements `$(document).on('click', '#click'` will save you a lot of time and trouble since 1) it doesn't need to be inside a `document ready` and 2) it listens for an even on 'document' and only cares about the `DOM` once "clicked"

Comment: @MarkSkayff the files are in the same directory, so it's not a problem of path, but in the console, when I click the div it's displayed the following error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/alessioinnocenzi/Scrivania/EasyRush/articoli.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: Could it be because I am working on local and not in the server?

Comment: @Alessio Ah, yes, indeed. It's because you are not running it on a server environemnt. So the file is called using the "file" protocol. The browser then protects the request by only allowing ajax calls to the same origin(server, http ... what you see there)

Comment: @MarkSkayff perfect, I tried to load it on the server and now it works. Thank you

Comment: @Alessio You can run a server in your local linux machine in several ways. You can either create a VirtualHost for your Apache2 local server, that's one. You can also run a server using the `php -S <local ip address>` command. That's an internal development server that comes with PHP from PHP 5.4.

Comment: @Alessio Good to know it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.ajax instead of load.

```
$.ajax({

  url: 'articoli.html',
  cache: false

}).done(function( result ){

  $('#toRefresh').html( result );

});
```

Comment: Load should be enough for what he is expecting.